# How to safely TRUNCATE and re-populate a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: spring, postgresql

One of the tables in my db has to be updated daily. A web server actively queries this table every 5 seconds. Now I can't simply `UPDATE` the table rows because of some constraints, so I need to clear all the rows and repopulate the table. How can I safely do this without affecting the functioning of web server?
The repopulation is done by an other web service isolated from the web server. I am using Spring framework.

The table has approx. 170k rows and 5 columns.

Comment: Just curious to know, why you want  to clear all the rows and repopulate the table ??, How do you need to repopulate  data ??

Comment: Assuming that you really *must* repopulate the table (just asking for confirmation because it's a pretty odd requirement), `drop table; create table;` is a whole lot faster than `delete from table;` - so it might be a good idea to plan that action between two requests of the webserver.

Comment: Why can't you update the rows? What are the constraints that prevent this? I why would they _not_ prevent deleting everything?

Comment: The table has a mapping of IP range(start ip to end ip) to countries. I download and parse this mapping from multiple sources, parse them and save them to the db. There is no primary key on the basis of which I can update the row. This is the constraint.

Comment: I don't understand... You need to truncate table and then populate it. So you can just `truncate table my_table;` and then populate it. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: I need to do it safely. Suppose the moment after I truncate the table, before it is repopulated again, my web service queries the table. At that point of time since the table is empty, my web service will fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Truncate and re-populate the table in a single transaction. <strike>The truncate isn't visible to concurrent readers, who continue to see the old data.</strike> Correction per @AlexanderEmelianov and [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html):

> TRUNCATE is not MVCC-safe. After truncation, the table will appear empty to concurrent transactions, if they are using a snapshot taken before the truncation occurred. See [Section 13.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-caveats.html) for more details.

so *after the `TRUNCATE`ing txn commits* , concurrent txns started *before* the `TRUNCATE` will see the table as empty.

---

Any transaction attempting to *write* to the table after it's truncated will wait until the transaction doing the truncate either commits or rolls back.

```
BEGIN;

TRUNCATE TABLE my_table;

INSERT INTO my_table (blah) VALUES (blah), (blah), (blah);

COMMIT;
```

You can `COPY` instead of `INSERT` too. Anything in a normal transaction.

Even better, there's an optimisation in PostgreSQL that makes populating a table after a truncate faster than if you do it otherwise.

Comment: Aah.. Totally forgot about transactions. Thanks. This works perfectly. :)

Comment: TRUNCATE is not MVCC-safe. After truncation, the table will appear empty to concurrent transactions, if they are using a snapshot taken before the truncation occurred. You can see it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html You can do DELETE in the transaction. It is MVCC-safe way.

Comment: @AlexanderEmelianov You sure/tested? I thought truncate was made MVCC-safe a long time ago...

Comment: @CraigRinger I am sure, certainly. I've caught few bugs, related to this behaviour of truncate. Moreover - this feature is written down in the official docs.

Comment: Current Postgres docs say it is not MVCC safe but is transaction safe

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html#:~:text=Description,requiring%20a%20subsequent%20VACUUM%20operation.